# How to get golbal data in main.js file in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, scope, vue.js

following code is from my main.js file. Here I am parsing data from a url using Vue object and it returns some array of data. Now, In the main.js file I have a another GraphChart object and here I need some data from tableData.

How it would be possible? or any other tricks ?
Now I am getting nothing.

```js
var tableData = new Vue({
  data: {
    items: ''
  },

  methods: {
    graphData: function () {
    var self = this;
    var testdata= '';
    $.get( 'http://localhost:3000/db', function( data ) {
        self.items = data;
        });
  },

  },

created: function() {
    this.graphData();
},
  computed:{

});


new GraphChart('.graph', {
  stroke: {
    width: 24,
    gap: 14
  },
  animation: {
    duration: -1,
    delay: -1
  },

  // series: needs data from ITEMS object
  series:items._data.radialChart[1]

}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you would be able to get the data using `tableData.items` if you left the creation of the chart where it is. I expect there might be a problem with that though, because the data is retrieved asynchronously, meaning the chart will be created before the data is returned.

It looks like you will need to move the code that creates the chart into the callback that gets your data.

```
$.get("http://localhost:3000/db", function(data) {
  self.items = data;

  new GraphChart(".graph", {
    stroke: {
      width: 24,
      gap: 14
    },
    animation: {
      duration: -1,
      delay: -1
    },
    series: self.items._data.radialChart[1]
  });
});
```

Also, you could replace `.graph` with a Vue reference, but you didn't post your template, so I'm not sure where `.graph` appears in your template. You might also need to wrap the creation of GraphChart in `$nextTick` if you continue to use `.graph`, in which case the code would be

```
$.get("http://localhost:3000/db", function(data) {
  self.items = data;

  self.$nextTick(() => {
    new GraphChart(".graph", {
      stroke: {
        width: 24,
        gap: 14
      },
      animation: {
        duration: -1,
        delay: -1
      },
      series: self.items._data.radialChart[1]
    });
  });
});
```